# Electron <webview>: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

When using my Electron app on Windows (problem doesn't appear on Mac) I started getting this error for some external URLs that are loaded into a `<webview>` tag: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` (which I believe refers to spread syntax).

It's hard for me to see a solution because of the fact it's an external URL. https://instagram.com is an example of as site that produces this error in my console.

This is my webview

```
<webview src="https://www.instagram.com/" preload="./custom_scripts/preload-manager.js" allowpopups="" webpreferences="webSecurity=no" partition="persist:default"></webview>
```

Using the Instagram example, this is the script that is throwing the error: https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/es6/ConsumerCommons.js/c86cd1388003.js.

Here is a snippet of that script that contains the position of the error

```
const {
  allowStale: c,
  onCached: v
} = {
  allowStale: !1,
  ...s
}, p = l[o];
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this. What version of Windows and Electron are you using? And you're seeing this error in the devtools of the webview? Does the page load at all?

Answer (score 0):

I encounted same problem. Enter the devtool of the external page and disable the cache in the network panel. It works. But I don't know why and how to get rid of this.

Comment: It's been a while since this was an issue. Since we got this, we have been updating Electron to the latest version whenever possible and haven't seen it since. Hope that's helpful